# Regarding notation of field extension of an extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, notation, extension-field

This is a fairly straightforward question regarding how we interpret extension of extensions. I just have not come across anyone who has specified this explicitly.

Suppose we have some field extension $K$ of a field $L$ such that $K=L(\alpha)$. Then what how would you regard $K(\beta)$? Would it be $L(\alpha\beta)$ or $L(\alpha, \beta)$?

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_extension#Examples $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2, \sqrt 3) = \mathbb Q (\sqrt 2)( \sqrt 3) $.

Comment: $L(\alpha, \beta)$ is correct. Which is the same as either $L(\alpha)(\beta)$ or $L(\beta)(\alpha)$. But $L(\alpha\beta)$ is definitely not correct..

Comment: $L(\alpha\beta)$ is a bad choice because it looks like an extension by the single element that is the product of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Answer (score 1):

The correct notation is $L(\alpha,\beta)$, or $L(\alpha)(\beta)$.  The notation $L(\alpha\beta)$ is incorrect because it refers to the smallest field which contains $L$ and the product $\alpha\cdot\beta$ (which is sometimes but not always the same as your $K(\beta)$).